# Whats wrong with the following mysql code

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Insert into hotel('fname', 'lname'...
values
  ('null', 'abc'....
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  fname = 'null',
  lname = 'abc',.....
```

Solve the above mysql query.

Comment: capitalization, for one thing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as you can see, you didn't enclose with `single quotes` the values which are not numeric,

```
Insert into child (`CASE`,`LASTNAME`,`FIRSTNAME`,`GENDER`,
                   `DOB`,`SSN`,`RACE`,`STREET`,`STREET2`,`CITY`,
                   `STATE`,`ZIP`,`PHONE`,`WORKPHONE`,`CELLPHONE`,
                   `PARENT NAME`,`GR`,`ADMITDATE`,`DISCHDATE`,
                   `WRK`,`WFIRSTNAME`,`WRKPHONE`)
VALUES ('null', 'Sivanesh', 'Jashawn', 'Male', '2002-03-08', 
        '206-80-2175', 'African American', '1689 Crucible Street', 
        'null', 'Pittsburgh', 'PA', '15210', '(412)458-3788', 
        'null', '(412)377-6079', 'Latel Williams', '2nd', '2010-03-17',
        'null', 'null', 'Addison', '(412)594-2545')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        LASTNAME = 'Sivanesh',
        FIRSTNAME= 'Jashawn',...
```

Comment: U mean in the values line or duplicate line. I have used single quotes for everything in values row. Please please help me.

Comment: yes, since all of them i think are varchar and date. only numeric values are not quoted with single (*but wrapping them is stil ok since the server automatically parses them*)

Comment: thanks, but now I get the following error. It would be really useful if you say me where the mistake is apart from editing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the values in your "KEY UPDATE" clause